# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'RAW_OPT'

Tags: ros, catkin

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/melodic/share/gencpp/cmake/../../../lib/gencpp/gen_cpp.py", line 50, in <module>
    sys.argv, msg_template_map, srv_template_map)
  File "/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/genmsg/template_tools.py", line 213, in generate_from_command_line_options
    generate_from_file(argv[1], options.package, options.outdir, options.emdir, options.includepath, msg_template_dict, srv_template_dict)
  File "/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/genmsg/template_tools.py", line 154, in generate_from_file
    _generate_msg_from_file(input_file, output_dir, template_dir, search_path, package_name, msg_template_dict)
  File "/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/genmsg/template_tools.py", line 99, in _generate_msg_from_file
    search_path)
  File "/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/genmsg/template_tools.py", line 77, in _generate_from_spec
    interpreter = em.Interpreter(output=ofile, globals=g, options={em.RAW_OPT:True,em.BUFFERED_OPT:True})
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'RAW_OPT'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/melodic/share/gencpp/cmake/../../../lib/gencpp/gen_cpp.py", line 50, in <module>
    sys.argv, msg_template_map, srv_template_map)
  File "/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/genmsg/template_tools.py", line 213, in generate_from_command_line_options
    generate_from_file(argv[1], options.package, options.outdir, options.emdir, options.includepath, msg_template_dict, srv_template_dict)
  File "/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/genmsg/template_tools.py", line 154, in generate_from_file
    _generate_msg_from_file(input_file, output_dir, template_dir, search_path, package_name, msg_template_dict)
  File "/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/genmsg/template_tools.py", line 99, in _generate_msg_from_file
    search_path)
  File "/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/genmsg/template_tools.py", line 77, in _generate_from_spec
    interpreter = em.Interpreter(output=ofile, globals=g, options={em.RAW_OPT:True,em.BUFFERED_OPT:True})
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'RAW_OPT'
Generating reconfiguration files for PathIntegralParams in autorally_control
Wrote header file in /home/autorally/catkin_ws/devel/include/autorally_control/PathIntegralParamsConfig.h
autorally/autorally_msgs/CMakeFiles/autorally_msgs_generate_messages_cpp.dir/build.make:106: recipe for target '/home/autorally/catkin_ws/devel/include/autorally_msgs/neuralNetLayer.h' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/autorally/catkin_ws/devel/include/autorally_msgs/neuralNetLayer.h] Error 1
make[2]: *** Deleting file '/home/autorally/catkin_ws/devel/include/autorally_msgs/neuralNetLayer.h'
autorally/autorally_msgs/CMakeFiles/autorally_msgs_generate_messages_cpp.dir/build.make:100: recipe for target '/home/autorally/catkin_ws/devel/include/autorally_msgs/line2D.h' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/autorally/catkin_ws/devel/include/autorally_msgs/line2D.h] Error 1
make[2]: *** Deleting file '/home/autorally/catkin_ws/devel/include/autorally_msgs/line2D.h'
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:3016: recipe for target 'autorally/autorally_msgs/CMakeFiles/autorally_msgs_generate_messages_cpp.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [autorally/autorally_msgs/CMakeFiles/autorally_msgs_generate_messages_cpp.dir/all] Error 2
```

I get this error when I catkin_make.

```
ERROR: the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys resolved
to system dependencies:
autorally_gazebo: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [effort_controllers]
```

I also get this error when I rosdep install.

Comment: Are you installing a package directly, or building from source? You can also try `rosdep update --include-eol-distros` since EOL distros don't always play nice with rosdep

Comment: I am building for the source

Comment: I am using conda Python 2.7 environment

Comment: I am still getting the "AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'RAW_OPT'" error

Answer (score 7):

To fix this issue I started by following an [old solution](https://github.com/ros/genmsg/issues/63#issue-157815747) of uninstalling *em* and installing *empy*. This alone wasn't enough though, because the latest version of empy (4.0) from November 30 seems to be causing this new issue of `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'RAW_OPT'`, so instead I installed an older version of *empy* as follows:

```
pip uninstall em
pip install empy==3.3.4
```

Comment: This was the case while making PX4-SITL from source (error caused by `PX4-Autopilot/Tools/msg/px_generate_uorb_topic_files.py`, line 261). Comment for the crawlers.